# How to scroll to the bottom inside of an element with selenium?

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium

I'm writing in C# with selenium. However, the best way I've found to scroll a page was to use:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
js.ExecuteScript("window.scrollBy(0,900);");
```

However, in my current case, the window I need to scroll is not the full page but a part of it. And this command doesn't do anything. I imagined that I need to select the element first so I tried something like this:

```
js.ExecuteScript("document.getElementsByClassName('scroller')[0].scrollBy(0,500)")
```

This didn't work either and I'm not sure if its because its wrong as I'm not particularly familiar with JS or if I'm doing something else wrong, like selecting the wrong element to try and scroll.

To sum up my questions are, is there a better way to scroll a window in c# selenium? Is my js code to try and scroll the element wrong? And is there a way to figure out which is the correct element i should try to scroll?

Comment: Instead of looking for scroller, look for the element which has the scrollbar, like on this page if you generate scrollbar by adding new lines in Answer textarea, you can use `document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].scrollTo(0,20)` to scroll it.

Comment: as far as I can tell the element with class scroll is the element that has the scroller. However I can't say for sure because there are a bunch nested divs in there. This seems to be the top element for that block of the page. as I mentioned in the post above I'm not quite sure how to figure out which element is the one that can be scrolled.

Comment: Hi @cybera, check my answer and let me know it is working for you or not? Thank you...

Comment: @Ali SCE I'm testing it right now.

Comment: @cybera, then I suggest you can select a few elements you think can be scrolled using the Chrome Devtools, and try `$0.scrollTo(0,20)` in the console on each. Once you find the correct element then you can find that element easily using one of the `document.getElements..` method. Without the actual url it will be hard to give exact solution for you I guess.

Comment: @Kamal, thanks I managed to check it by writing the js command in the console with various options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `scrollIntoView(true);` to do that, it will brings up the passed element view.

Suppose that you want to scroll until the below element

```
WebElement element = driver.getElementByClassName('scroller');
```

then you can do like this :

```
js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```

For multiple elements, you can try the below by passing a matching index number :

```
js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", driver.getElementsByClassName('scroller')[pass the index number here]);
```

Comment: it doesn't work. scroller is not the element which i'm trying to scroll into view its the class of the block that can be scrolled. I'm trying to scroll to the bottom of that box.

Comment: Take some element from the bottom of the box and try to pass, it will scroll to there... The scrolling itself not working or what you want is not working?

Comment: OK. I managed to get it to scroll, but I think the site is crap. When I scroll the element like this, it scrolls it without the scroller moving and when I reach the bottom of the preloaded elements it stops because the scroller icon has not moved and it requires it to be to the bottom. So I guess I'll have to switch from scrolling to figuring out how to move the scroller icon. Thanks for the help.