# How can i get the length of entire list of followers instagram with selenium

Tags: python, list, selenium, loops, for-loop

Hellow! I want to iterate over entire list of followers on instagram but it gets me just the first 13 elements! Why this happend?
[image]

```html
abc = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="_7UhW9   xLCgt        qyrsm            uL8Hv        T0kll "]')
for i in abc:
     if i.text == 'Follow':
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", i)
```

[image]

Any ideea how to click on all ements from the followrs pop up?

Comment: Probably the entire list isn't loaded initially. That's why the scrollbar doesn't go down that far. More elements get loaded in as you scroll down. So try first scrolling to the bottom of the page like 10 times, or for a minute, or until the last element stops changing. Then get all the elements in selenium and then click them all.

Comment: i understood but how after scroll how i can get all elements in selenium?

Comment: You would have to know what you can use to select these elements. If you type in a CSS selector or XPath in the elements inspector in devtools on a browser (hitting `ctrl + f` in there), it will show you what elements you are selecting. I'll type up an answer to be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you're looking at a list of followers on Instagram.

So here is a random page on IG:
[image: IG screencap]

They have 218,000 followers but when I click to see, I only see 24 followers:
[image: IG screencap]

More elements load in when **scrolling down**:
[image: IG screencap]
You can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54763058/how-to-scroll-to-the-bottom-inside-of-an-element-with-selenium) answer for how to scroll within a specific element

If you would want to get all the followers, I would recommend looping your scrollToBottom() method until the last element stops changing. I don't know how well this will work for 218,000 elements though.

To select the scrolling area, you'll need to find a CSS selector or XPath that matches with this element. Since all the classes here look like they are autogenerated they keep changing, so I found that this selector gets the scrolling area everytime: `div[aria-label="Followers"] >div >div >div:nth-child(2)`
[image]
(I try to just use CSS selectors when working with Selenium, but you can use XPath if you want)

In Selenium, to access the element you can use

element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div[aria-label="Followers"] >div >div >div:nth-child(2)')

After loading in however many elements you want, you just gotta use the `find_elements_by_css_selector()` method to get the followers.

I've found this one works consistently:

`div[aria-label="Followers"] >div >div >div:nth-child(2) > ul li`

If you're just trying to mass follow all these people, I would advise against it, you might get flagged if you don't add some delay between clicks. But simply you could do this:

```
followButtons = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div[aria-label="Followers"] >div >div >div:nth-child(2) > ul li button')
for butt in followButtons:
    butt.click()
```

If anything happens though, I wasn't involved

Comment: Okay, it will stay beetwen us :)))! It doesen t work!  i will post an answer to share photos!